# ffmpeg image input use odd or even at input level in Windows

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

There are several solutions to select the every odd or even image at the filter level and they all work. But in my case I have an input of 15360x8640 .jpg files where it makes quite a difference whether I input all images and throw away every second in the filter or whether I skip every second input image. It would speed up encoding a lot.
My normal input is (for five digit numeric files, running on win10 x64):

```
ffmpeg.exe -framerate 60 -i %05d.jpg -vcodec libx264 out.mkv
```

What I tried (taken from [this thread](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7300/how-to-get-ffmpeg-to-join-non-sequential-image-files-skip-by-3s), might only work on linux but i couldn't check):

```
ffmpeg.exe -framerate 60 -i %04d%[13579%].jpg -vcodec libx264 out.mkv
```

and various variants with and without glob options and so on. All fail. Always resulting in "%04d%[13579%].jpg: No such file or directory" or something alike.

A working example for every tenth frame (i.e. 00001 00011 00021 etc).

```
ffmpeg.exe -framerate 60 -i %04d1.jpg -vcodec libx264 out.mkv
```

Anybody already solved the problem or got a new idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently a two-step solution.
Create list:

`dir *1.jpg *3.jpg *5.jpg *7.jpg *9.jpg /b /on | c:\prog\unix\sed "s/^/file /" > "!list.txt"`

Use list:

`ffmpeg.exe -r 60 -f concat -safe 0 -i "!list.txt" -vcodec libx264 out.mkv`

Pro: Saves me about a terabyte just to have a copy of those files differently named as input or decoding time on input level. Nearly 1.5x speed compared to convert at filter level with my huge .jpgs as input.
Con: Seems to require more ram than using it at filter level, but why?
Anybody got a better solution?